# Best way to create console commands in php that alias a composer package command?

Tags: php

I am creating a php framework and am using various other libraries. Some of which come with commands that must be run like so

```
vendor/bin/phinx migrate
```

my question is, how do I somehow alias these commands so instead of typing in

```
vendor/bin/phinx migrate
```

I can type

```
php something-here migrate
```

kind of like how the Laravel framework does it with

```
php artisan migrate
```

I have tried making a file called `something-here` and using a switch statement on `$argv` and checking the case for `$argv[1]` and using `echo shell_exec('vendor/bin/phinx migrate')` this works but I think there must be a better way, and i can imagine this is not the most secure way. and maybe possibly I can retain the terminal colors? Just to be clear I am using composer.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a little old, but might still be worth to answer.

This answer is for linux only and you need to edit your bash-shell.

Open the file `~/.bashrc` and at the end of the file, add te following line:

```
alias phinx='vendor/bin/phinx'
```

Save the file and install it.

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Now you can use the phinx command like:

```
$ phinx migrate
```